# javascript trying to get 3rd nested array.length and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a generated nested Array which I store some data.

How can i get the 3rd nested array (in this case the array starting with "yellow")

the array looks like this (this is a dynamically generated array):

```
[
    ["Large", 
       ["yellow", "green", "Blue"],
       ["$55.00", "$55.00", "$55.00"]
     ]
    ["Medium",
       ["yellow", "green", "Blue", "Red"],
       ["$55.00", "$55.00", "$55.00", "$55.00"]
    ]
    ["small",
       ["yellow", "green", "Blue", "Red"],
       ["$55.00", "$55.00", "$55.00", "$55.00"]
    ]
]
```

I am trying to get to the ["yellow", "green", "Blue"] array's length and loop to get the values

```
for(i=0; colorNSize.dataArray[0][0][1].length<i; i++){
    alert(colorNSize.dataArray[colorNSize.Sizeindex][0][0][i])// alert's A (which is the char[1] of the second array.
}
```

`alert(colorNSize.dataArray[0][0][1].length)` actually alerts the length of "Large" which is "5"
is there a limit for nested arrays?
Can i still get the real 3rd array nested here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formatting is probably wrong - does "Large" reside in the same array as the array of colors and then prices? Indentation tells it is, brackets say it's all nested. Have you forgotten a bracket after the array of prices?

Anyway, `[0][0][1]` already refers to chars of "Large". `[0][0]` is "Large", `[0][1]` is the other array.

Consider this simplified example:

```
>>> arr = [['large', [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]
[["large", [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]]
>>> arr[0]
["large", [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
>>> arr[0][0]
"large"
>>> arr[0][1]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> arr[0][1][0]
[1, 2]
```

Can you see what's going on?

Comment: Can you please explain? 
how can i get the 3rd array?

Comment: in your answer i see the last example..  `>>> arr[0][1]`...
Can you please add a 3rd nest example?

Comment: @adardesign: alright, added the 3rd nest. You can have a 4th one too, in my example, just by adding more indexing

Comment: Correct.  My mistake..

May i ask you?  is @Chetan correct that objects will make more sense?

Comment: @adardesign: it's hard to say without knowing your real application, but the way your data looks he may well be right

Answer (score 3):

Why does everything have to be an array? This structure makes much more sense to me.

```
obj = {
    "Large": {
       "yellow": "$55.00",
       "green": "$55.00",
       "Blue": "$55.00"
    },
    "Medium": {
    ...
    ...
]
```

To get the Large, yellow price, all I have to do is

```
obj["Large"]["yellow"] //or obj.Large.yellow
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant call ["Large"] since i don't know the values at run-time

Comment: @adardesign: Ok. As a rule of thumb, use arrays when you are representing lists of data you want to process as a batch and objects when you want to lookup fast by a property. You can have arrays nested inside objects or vice versa based on the above rule.